# Get file path (not the executable) where application is running from?

Tags: python, executable, desktop-application

I used pyinstaller to convert py into exe, for opening .jpg files.
I would like to get the jpg path (not the executable) where my application is running from, so that it can open the jpg directly by double-clicking the jpg.

Could you advise how to achieve this in python?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not the path "where my application is running from".  If you double-click on a JPG and your script is configured to act as an opener for JPGs, then the file name will be passed on the command line.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Tried sys.argv[1] and it works, while os.getcwd() returned "C:\WINDOWS\system32". Not sure why the comment was removed but thanks!